# CodeIgniter - Prevent problems caused by editing <form> action using Inspect Element

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, google-chrome-devtools

I'm pretty sure every web developer is aware that the content of webpages can be edited using the Inspect Element function of our browsers.

For example, I can actually edit the value of a form's action attribute, submit it immediately (without refreshing) and have the form's values be posted to the URL equivalent to the new value I edited.

This poses a serious loophole to my implementation of a page commenting functionality similar to Facebook. I use CodeIgniter. What I do is I pass the ID of the page where the user is commenting as a parameter in the URL.

```
<?php 
echo form_open(base_url().'pages/process_comment/'.$page_id, $attributes) 
?>
```

The resulting markup looks like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost/myproject/index.php/pages/process_comment/3" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="comment" name="comment">
    <textarea name='comment_content'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' id='post' name='post' value='post' />
</form>
```

The danger of this implementation is that I can edit the page_id which is 3, to something else, and when I submit the comment, it would posted to a different page since it references a different page_id. How do I prevent this? Is there any better implementation? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution is this:

In the database I added a column named identifierHash, and assigned it a 9 character hashed value. Then in the form I would have the form action link to index.php/controller/postFunction. The form would contain two hidden values, One with the userID and the other with this hash. Both have to match up to be able to post correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably what I'm looking for. I have actually used this in my user table which was primarily used for validation emails but I didn't realize I could implement it for pages. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Posting is client server. So you should always check if the user is allowed to post on the thread. Or if any values are incorrect/invalid.
This must be checked on server side.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. But given the case that a user is allowed to post on that comment and the page_id value he entered using the Inspect Element actually exists and is valid, how could I prevent the issue on the server side?

Comment: If the user is allowed to post on both, and they're just doing it because (I can't think of a reason that makes sense), who cares? They've just found a really convoluted and silly way to do something they were allowed to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any better implementation?*

With this perspective (protecting from developer tools), probably no. Read on.

When somebody is using developer tools, he/she ought to be careful and he is responsible for what he does. I could post a hundred comments on standard websites using tools such as "Advanced Rest Client" - but I am responsible for the mess created because of that, not the developer of the website. The best the developer can do is develop a good algorithm to detect spam.

In fact, when web services are available, you could post comments or other data without ever opening the frontend of the website!! However, this problem can be limited where captcha is used in an appropriate manner. This, in turn, will ensure that you do indeed take a look at the front end.

So, to answer to your question, there is a way you can make it more *difficult* for a developer to accidentally submit with wrong values: You can create a page-specific "token" - which can again be manipulated, but it is difficult to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One way to *help* prevent this would be to use encryption. Something like

```
echo form_hidden('page_id', $this->encrypt->encode($page_id));
```

and use that instead of the param in the URL to determine the id of the page being posted to. It can still be manipulated but would be quite an undertaking for an attacker to find out what the value is/means and how to exploit it.